# Why does my list print from the last index?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Im learning python on Codecademy and this task prints the list from the last index to 6. Why doesn't it prints from the first index to 6?

```py
all_students = ["Alex", "Briana", "Cheri", "Daniele", "Dora", "Minerva", "Alexa", "Obie", "Arius", "Loki"]
    
students_in_poetry = []
while len(students_in_poetry) < 6:
  student = all_students.pop()
  students_in_poetry.append(student)

print(students_in_poetry)
```

the output is:
`['Loki', 'Arius', 'Obie', 'Alexa', 'Minerva', 'Dora']`

Comment: it has to do with `pop`, `pop` takes out the last element from the list

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do not forget to look at the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) first: usually, the answer is on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with

```py
student = all_students.pop()
```

the last element will be removed from the list and assigned to `student`

But you can use `pop(0)` to get the first element, so your code becomes

```py
all_students = ["Alex", "Briana", "Cheri", "Daniele", "Dora", "Minerva", "Alexa", "Obie", "Arius", "Loki"]

students_in_poetry = []
while len(students_in_poetry) < 6:
  student = all_students.pop(0) # this pops out the first element
  students_in_poetry.append(student)

print(students_in_poetry)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `pop()` takes out the last item in the list.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_pop.asp

In your code you then put the last item at the end of the second list effectively reversing the order.

Answer (score 0):

The `.pop()` method pops the **last** index of the list.

But you could try :

`all_students.reverse().pop()`

This reverses the list and then pops the last one which is the first in `.reverse()`

edit: my bad the `.reverse()` returns `None` you can use it before the loop like this :

`all_students = ["Alex", "Briana", "Cheri", "Daniele", "Dora", "Minerva", "Alexa", "Obie", "Arius", "Loki"]`

`all_students.reverse()`

Then your loop here.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `pop(0)` to `lpop()` and you will pop from the left side of the list; no need to reverse the list. Just use `.lpop()`